# limit select on certain Domain Class Items

Tags: grails

My Domain Classes simplified look like this:

```
class ScheduleTimeExp{
     Data date
}

class ScheduleAction{
     ScheduleTimeExp scheduleTimeExp
}
```

I have a select box in my gsp:

```
<g:select id="scheduleTimeExp" name="scheduleTimeExp.id" from="${tao.marketing.ScheduleTimeExp.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${tao.marketing.ScheduleAction?.scheduleTimeExp?.id}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

Rather that letting the user select from all ScheduleTimeExp

```
from="${tao.marketing.ScheduleTimeExp.list()}"
```

I would like to show only those ScheduleTimeExp where a relation between ScheduleTimeExp and ScheduleAction does not exist for any other ScheduleAction. In other words only those time expressions which have not yet been selected in another ScheduleAction.

Comment: You might want to include your domain classes to offer the opportunity for higher quality answers.

Comment: is the association between `ScheduleTimeExp` and `ScheduleAction` 1:1 or n:1 ?

Comment: in your controller you should get the required data from service and send to gsp as list in params

Comment: I am not 100 % sure about the association. 
One ScheduleAction can only have relation with one ScheduleTimeExp but one ScheduleTimeExp can have a relation with many ScheduleActions.

Comment: @user3675091 you can pikup all ScheduleAction with ScheduleTimeExp and receive ScheduleTimeExp.id in they, after you can call a findAllByIdNotInList(). thats all

Answer (score 0):

To enforce logic from presentation separation, you want to fill the list inside controller action:

```
def dataSource

def someAction() {
  final Sql sql = new Sql( dataSource )
  def scheduleTimeExps = sql.rows( 'select ste.id, ste.date from Schedule_Time_Exp ste where ste.id not in (select sa.Schedule_Time_Exp_id from Schedule_Action sa)' ).collect{ it as ScheduleTimeExp }
  [ ..., scheduleTimeExps:scheduleTimeExps ]
}
```

Note: make sure the case and naming of the tables and columns are correct

and then in gsp:

```
<g:select .. from="${scheduleTimeExps}"/>
```